# How to spin the fans such as your cpu cooler with a python script?

Tags: python

So, i have basic knowledge of python, and i'd like to know how to spin fans such as the case fans or the cpu cooling fans or even the Power supply fans. i have looked up on this, but haven't really found anything helpful, thank you everyone. PS,i already know about pypi but i can't install it, im thinking of using the info i find out to make a program that detects if your cpu is getting too hot or your fans are spinning too fast.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479558/controlling-the-fan-speed-and-detecting-the-inside-temperature-of-the-pc-with-py  TL;DR: don't do it unless you know what you're doing: you could fry your computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling the fan speed and detecting the inside temperature of the pc with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479558/controlling-the-fan-speed-and-detecting-the-inside-temperature-of-the-pc-with-py)