# open source software to control computer fan speed

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, motherboard

So I asked a similar question here but it was considered a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6181191/319862

This time I will be a little bit more specific...

Are there any open source projects that can control the pwm frequency of a motherboard fan header.  Please share links.  The only software I can find is Speedfan and it does not seem to make the source available.

The next best thing I found was [openhardwaremonitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/), but it does not control fan speeds yet according to the issues list on google code.

-- edit --

I am mainly interested in Windows at this time, although a cross platform project would be great.

Comment: Are you looking for working software, or just the code to do this with an open source licence? Please clarify this. There are probably relevant answers about APIs for controlling fans at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786984/how-can-i-control-my-pcs-fan-speed-using-c-in-vista. You included a C# tag so I'm assuming this is an indication that you are using the Windows platform.

Comment: I edited my post to specify Windows.  I am looking for working code that I could read over.  I want to understand how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[lm-sensors](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/man/fancontrol) provides a `fancontrol` tool that can change the speed of your fans, along with some nice calibration tools to help you maintain reasonable temperatures with minimum energy and noise. Excellent tools.

Comment: I upvoted this because I did not specify Windows and this is a good tool for linux