# Control/Read computer fans using .NET?

Tags: .net, hardware

What I'd like to do is to monitor / control my computer fans using C# or VB.Net. Is there any .NET library that allows me to do this in a simple way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [Win32_Fan_Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394146%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which is accessible through [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa394084) (WMI) - which .NET through System.Management, if I recall correctly.

Hope this helps you out.

Edit: Here are a couple of related links/questionsthat I found regarding fan / hardware access through code (primarily in C++, but could be useful to some)

[Programatically Access Fan on a Laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485448/programmatically-access-cpu-fan-on-a-laptop-windows)

[Using WMI in C# - DreamInCode.net](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/42934-using-wmi-class-in-c%23/)

Comment: Find me a consumer PC/motherboard that exposes that info, and I'll try send you $10.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/). It is an opensource .NET project.