# Fancontroller for windows using a android phone

Tags: android, windows, bluetooth, controller

I'm thinking of an app for android phone and for a windows pc, that makes android control the fans in a computer and get other information about the pc.

The problem that i having is that, I have no idea how to make either of them.

**So my question is:** What is the best link method between the pc and the phone? Wifi, usb, bluetooth ? What is the best language to write such a application in (for the pc) ? How do I control the fans based on input from the phone ?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: To write the program, who can access data from fan I would suggest C/C++, and to send it to your android device, then I would use a database where you would store all those data. To transfer data you should use WiFi
This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485448/programmatically-access-cpu-fan-on-a-laptop-windows) will help you a lot!

Comment: Okay thanks m8, I'll look intro it :) have a nice day !

Comment: This will be a very hard and long term project, but if you make it, then I can only say well done! :D
Any further question or help, fell free to ask.

Comment: Thanks again m8! I've got a question about the connection between the android device and the computer, is it p2p or plain old ftp ?

Comment: I'll sum all the comments in one answer in a couple of minutes, It might help others too... I'll explain you how can you connect the device and pc...

Comment: That's just awesome ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To write the program, who can access data from fan I would suggest C/C++/C#/Python, and to send it to your android device, then I would use a database where you would store all those data. To transfer data you should use WiFi This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485448/programmatically-access-cpu-fan-on-a-laptop-windows) will help you a lot! And about connecting the device and android phone. My suggestion is to store all the data to a database. That way you wont have any direct contact PC-Cell phone. The cell phone device will get all the data from the database, and the PC will store the data to the same database. Now where to store THE database, that is up to you. If you store it on your PC (the same PC as from the one you are getting the data and storing the data) then you will have to be same connection to get all the data to your android device.