# Get fan speed Python windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to get fan speed with Python on Windows? `psutil.sensors_fans()` only works with Linux and most of questions related are about temperature.

Comment: Have you tried [`wmi`](https://pypi.org/project/WMI/)?

Comment: I did, it doesn't give me anything

Comment: Have you seen this post [Programmatically access CPU fan on a laptop? (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485448/programmatically-access-cpu-fan-on-a-laptop-windows)